# How to give arguments to Class in python

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a Django app. I want create function to pass some initial text to text area. I tried following:

Here is required part of `views.py` :

```
    from django import forms
    
    class createform(forms.Form):
        def __init__(self, title, value):
            self.newtitle = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Enter Title:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': title}))
            self.content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'value': value}), label='Enter the description:')

    def create(request):
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "form": createform('this title','this content')
        })
```

Here is my `create.html` file:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Create New Page
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    
    <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post" class="createnew">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create New Page">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is `url.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>/", views.entries, name="entries"),
    path("find/", views.find, name="find"),
    path("create/", views.create, name="create")
]
```

But when I try to run this I get following error:

[image: snippet of error]

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Do I need to add url.py?

Comment: attach code at `/create/` view, where you use `renderer`

Comment: Hint: are you sure you override the `__init__` method properly? Is the method originally supposed to do anything else? What about the method signature, have you  preserved the original method signature?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat
 I am sorry. I don't understand. Initially I wanted to pass some text as argument to the the `class createform` so that I can put some text initially in textarea. I saw some solutions where  `__init__` was used to take arguments. I don't actually know much about it. Sorry to be dumb.

Comment: @oruchkin I never used keyword `renderer`

Comment: @MWD It is because you haven't call `super()` that's why it has not attribute `renderer` when you call it, it will go to actual `__init__` of forms.py of django, from there it has been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is because you haven't call `super()` inside the `__init__`, pass it as:

views.py

```
class createform(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, title, value):
        self.newtitle = forms.CharField(
            max_length=30, label='Enter Title:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': title}))
        self.content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'value': value}), label='Enter the description:')

        super().__init__(title, value)

def create(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "form": createform('this title','this content')
    })
```

Generally, when forms are made without the use of models, i.e. through Form API, it is generally made it as following:

views.py

```
class createform(forms.Form):
    newtitle = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30, label='Enter Title:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={}),initial='this title')
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={}),
                              label='Enter the description:',initial='this content')
```

Then, pass it as empty form in view as:

```
def create(request):
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "form": createform()
        })
```

> `Note:` Classes in python are written in **PascalCase** not <s>**smallcase**</s>, so you may change it to `CreateForm` from <s>`createform`</s>.

Comment: is the big bracket in 8th line last column unintended?

Comment: @MWD What mean? Call the super() with respective fields.

Comment: It does work but the form doesn't render

Comment: @MWD can you share your models? and do you mean form is not appearing?

Comment: You should also preserve the actual signature of the `__init__` method. With this implementation there is no way to pass in the various arguments the form originally can  take.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Make edit to my answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was making problem too much complex. If I want to provide the initial text to text area I can simply do this:

`views.py` :

```
 class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    newtitle = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Enter Title:')
     content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Enter the description:')

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = createform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_title = form.cleaned_data["newtitle"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]

            if util.get_entry(new_title):
                return HttpResponse("OOPS! Entry with the title already exists")

            util.save_entry(new_title, content)

            return entries(request, new_title)

    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "form": CreateForm(initial={
                "newtitle" : "this title",
                "content" : "this content"
            })
        })
```

***Edit***: Thanks Abdul Aziz Barkat for your suggestion.Used `initial`.

Comment: Why you didn't share the full view? and it is already done by me in the second approach :)

Comment: The [`initial` kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) is more suitable the form will  interpret what you currently do as the user passing that data in.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Can you give me link to the page that shows the implementation difference between these two

Comment: The first argument the form class takes is the form data, as you yourself wrote `createform(request.POST)` this will make the form  _bound_ to some data, the `initial` kwarg on the other hand is specifically for the purpose of specifying initial values and will not cause the form to be bound.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Why you rolled back to previous revision, since you suggested that's why I made an edit.

Comment: @SunderamDubey your edit broke OP's answer by removing the values from there. Their code (although not ideal) would have worked before your edit. My suggestion was to use the `initial` kwarg.